# How to find next blank row and export form data to excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, forms

I can currently currently export each textBox to an individual cell on row 2. However it can only write to that location which overwrites the previous data. I am trying to figure out how to make it identify the next available blank row after every submission. Below is my current code that only write to row 2. This is my first project in C# so I do not have much C# knowledge.

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets xlBigSheet;

   object misValue;
   String myPath;
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       string myPath = @"C:\\Users\\N0m4d\\Desktop\\Longhouse\\database.xlsx"; // this must be full path.
       FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(myPath);
       if (!fi.Exists)
       {
           Console.Out.WriteLine("file doesn't exists!");
       }
       else
       {
           var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
           var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);
           Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;


           Range range1 = worksheet.Cells[2, 1] as Range;
           range1.Value2 = textBox1.Text;
           Range range2 = worksheet.Cells[2, 2] as Range;
           range2.Value2 = textBox2.Text;
           Range range3 = worksheet.Cells[2, 3] as Range;
           range3.Value2 = textBox3.Text;
           Range range4 = worksheet.Cells[2, 4] as Range;
           range4.Value2 = textBox4.Text;
           Range range5 = worksheet.Cells[2, 5] as Range;
           range5.Value2 = textBox5.Text;
           Range range6 = worksheet.Cells[2, 6] as Range;
           range6.Value2 = textBox6.Text;

           excelApp.Visible = true;
           workbook.Save();
           //workbook.Close();

           textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox6.Text = string.Empty;

           xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlBigSheet.get_Item("Sheet1");
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range last = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
           int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
           getData(lastUsedRow + 1);
       }
   }

   private void getData(int lastRow_)
   {

       lastRow_ = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
                   "*",
                   xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                   misValue,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                   misValue,
                   misValue,
                   misValue).Row + 1;
   }
```

Comment: var totalUsedColumns = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
var totalUsedRows = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea I am getting this error after placing your recommendation System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: hmm, it depends where you put that code, it should replace the xlCellTypeLastCell code, but now that   I've reread your code... xlCellTypeLastCell should work too. This was not the problem. Ah.. you are explicitly writing to the 2nd row. What you want to do is calculate range 1 through 6 before you write any data:  Range range1 = worksheet.Cells[lastrow, 1] as Range; etc.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. In which sheet do you want to write after the last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets xlBigSheet;

   object misValue;
   String myPath;
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       string myPath = @"C:\\Users\\N0m4d\\Desktop\\Longhouse\\database.xlsx"; // this must be full path.
       FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(myPath);
       if (!fi.Exists)
       {
           Console.Out.WriteLine("file doesn't exist!");
       }
       else
       {
           var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
           var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);
           Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;

      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range lastRow = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
           int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
           int newRow = lastUsedRow + 1;

           Range range1 = worksheet.Cells[newRow , 1] as Range;
           range1.Value2 = textBox1.Text;
           Range range2 = worksheet.Cells[newRow , 2] as Range;
           range2.Value2 = textBox2.Text;
           Range range3 = worksheet.Cells[newRow , 3] as Range;
           range3.Value2 = textBox3.Text;
           Range range4 = worksheet.Cells[newRow , 4] as Range;
           range4.Value2 = textBox4.Text;
           Range range5 = worksheet.Cells[newRow , 5] as Range;
           range5.Value2 = textBox5.Text;
           Range range6 = worksheet.Cells[newRow , 6] as Range;
           range6.Value2 = textBox6.Text;

           excelApp.Visible = true;
           workbook.Save();
           //workbook.Close();

           textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
           textBox6.Text = string.Empty;
       }
   }
```

Comment: your latest code has got me very close to the solution. I am trying to write to sheet one. I fixed the code according to your suggestion however it is only writing to row 33 on the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @N0m4d1k you select the desired sheet by saying var sheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets["SheetName"];

Comment: I have got it to move to the next row but it starts at row 33.

Comment: @N0m4d1k have you tried with a new excel file? Perhaps row 32 contains data in your sheet, you can check which column the last cell detection returns. You can try manually deleting row 32 to make sure.

Comment: Ok i created a blank excel doc and it is writing to row 2 now. I will try to keep tinkering with it and see if i can fix it. Thanks for the help!